# Get Datediff() working with Max() as input

Tags: sql, sql-server

To get the max between 2 values I use the following:

```sql
SELECT 
    (SELECT MAX(cost)
     FROM (VALUES (cost_tran_recur.date_start),(GETDATE())) AS Allcosts(cost))
FROM
    cost_tran_recur
```

and it works fine. But when I try to use the same query in `datediff`, I get an error:

```sql
SELECT
    (amount_expense * DATEDIFF(m, SELECT (SELECT MAX(cost)
                                          FROM (VALUES (cost_tran_recur.date_start),(GETDATE())) AS Allcosts(cost))
                                  FROM cost_tran_recur,  date_end)) AS TOTALS 
FROM
    (SELECT ......) AS table1
```

Please any suggestions?

Comment: You forgot to put said error in your question.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you are over-nesting things here. It looks like the query you want to write is:

```
SELECT 
    amount_expense * DATEDIFF(
        m,
        (
            SELECT MAX(cost)
            FROM (VALUES (date_start), (GETDATE())) AS Allcosts(cost)
        ),
        date_end
    ) AS TOTALS 
FROM cost_tran_recur
```

I find that `VALUES()` seems a bit overkill for what you are trying to do. A `CASE` expression gets the job done with less typing and less overhead:

```
SELECT 
    amount_expense * DATEDIFF(
        m,
        CASE WHEN date_start >= GETDATE() THEN date_start else GETDATE() end,
        date_end
    ) AS TOTALS 
FROM cost_tran_recu
```